# Quick Edit problems. Need help

Tags: quick-edit

so our environment has got some issues in regards to the quick edit link for lists and libraries. Quick edit is enabled but when clicked, it doesn't refresh the content with table view. In order for us to get it into table view, we have to click on the edit link first then click on a list item. This will then put the list in table view to allow quick edits to a list/library.

The problem seems to deal with the JS behind the onclick function for the "edit" link and the Quick Edit button within the ribbon.

Debugging in both IE and Chrome give me the same exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OK' of undefined
>   InitGrid  @   inplview.js?rev=Uv%2BQls0Zz16uHFi33RrTcA%3D%3D:1
>   InitGridFromView  @   inplview.js?rev=Uv%2BQls0Zz16uHFi33RrTcA%3D%3D:1
>   EnsureScriptParams.d  @   init.js?rev=0%2BjgcYFw8Xoj0N42kzP%2BcQ%3D%3D:1
>   EnsureScript  @   init.js?rev=0%2BjgcYFw8Xoj0N42kzP%2BcQ%3D%3D:1
>   EnsureScriptFunc  @   init.js?rev=0%2BjgcYFw8Xoj0N42kzP%2BcQ%3D%3D:1
>   EnsureScriptParams    @   init.js?rev=0%2BjgcYFw8Xoj0N42kzP%2BcQ%3D%3D:1
>   onclick   @   VM28108 AllItems.aspx:991

It seems this issue only exists on one web application as all site collections within this web app are affected.

Any help in helping me understand why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you forcing compatibility mode on IE?

Comment: Yes, my site has been added to compatibility mode.

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding this script to the masterpage:

<Sharepoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.dialog.js');
</Sharepoint:ScriptBlock >
-n